# Split column into two while keeping delimiter in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to split column `A` into 2 columns `results1` and `results2` with the **first** delimiter `<` appeared in the string while keeping the delimiter.

Currently I'm using:

```
df[['result1', 'result2']] = df['A'].str.split('<', 1, expand=True)
```

but it removes the delimiter `<` after the split.

Expected output:

```
     A                    C          result1     result2
0    NaN                  NaN        NaN         NaN
1    TEXT info <1 <1 <1   >1         TEXT info   <1 <1 <1
2    EXAM<10              NaN        EXAM        <10
```

Is there a Pythonic way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create helper column `tmp` with separator and add to second column:

```
df[['result1', 'tmp','result2']] = df['A'].str.split('(<)', 1, expand=True)
df['result2'] = df.pop('tmp') + df['result2']
print (df)
         A    C result1 result2
0      NaN  NaN     NaN     NaN
1   TEXT<1   >1    TEXT      <1
2  EXAM<10  NaN    EXAM     <10
```

---

```
#adde \s* for remove space before first <
df[['result1', 'tmp','result2']] = df['A'].str.split('\s*(<)', 1, expand=True)
df['result2'] = df.pop('tmp') + df['result2']
print (df)
                    A    C    result1   result2
0                 NaN  NaN        NaN       NaN
1  TEXT info <1 <1 <1   >1  TEXT info  <1 <1 <1
2             EXAM<10  NaN       EXAM       <10
```

Comment: Hi jezrael, thanks for the  answer. I made a change in the question, as I realised that there could be multiple `<` in the string. Please see edited question

Comment: @nilsinelabore - there is parameter `1`, so it split by first `<`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str.extract` here:

```py
df["result1"] = df["A"].str.extract(r'^(.*?)\s*<')
df["result2"] = df["A"].str.extract(r'(<.*)$')
```

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for your answer. Sorry I made a change in the question, as I realised that there could be multiple `<` in the string.

Comment: I have updated my answer, which didn't change much.

Comment: Thank you, it caught an error `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'`

Comment: I don't believe my code should be generating that error.

Comment: Hmm could it be my data? Don't worry it's solved :)

Comment: I fixed it, I guess I'm too late.

Comment: Awesome, it's working now. An alternative solution is always helpful :) Thank you.